# Unable to open dialogflow console

Tags: console, dialogflow-es

After changing my Google Account ID, the Dialogflow console no longer opens. Please tell me how to solve it.
It seems that others have reported such cases.
(example)
 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154760284

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to access the console directly, and it is causing trouble to load the page.

Try this:

1. Go to Dialogflow and click "Sign-in" instead of clicking "Go to Console" directly
2. After logging-in, now click "Go to Console"
3. Dialogflow will prompt you "Sign-in with Google".
4. Select your Google Account from the list of Logged In accounts.

Dialogflow will now redirect you to the console.